# How to incresae speed of bulk insert from Oracle to IBM DB2 via Apache NiFi

Tags: oracle, db2, apache-nifi

I am just curious of ways to better tune for speed bulk inserts via apache nifi. I am just curious if a different driver or other configurations could speed up the process. Any inputs or references to resources would be greatly appreciated!

This is my current flow with configurations included in pictures, Source DB is Oracle, Destination DB is IBM db2 z/Os:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running a NiFi cluster, or a stand-alone server?

Comment: at which point is Apache Spark used here?

Comment: @pmdba I am using this on a hadoop cluster,

Comment: You could try increasing the concurrent tasks setting on each processor, playing with the fetch size on the ingest processor, and freeing the PutDatabaseRecord processor to run on any node (currently it is set to primary only). Other than that you'd probably get the most performance gain by tuning the respective databases.

Comment: @pmdba do you know if changing the driver would increase the speed at all?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I suspect (based on recent personal experience) that it wouldn't have as much of an effect as parallelizing the pipeline where possible and tuning the database transactions themselves.

Comment: I have increased the concurrent tasks to help with the load, The fetchsize I've found is optimized at 100k for my flow and 9 threads thanks for the help all

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few things working against you:

1. You probably have low concurrency set on the `PutDatabaseRecord` processor.
2. You have a very large fetch size.
3. You have a very large record-per-flowfile count.

From what I've read in the past, the fetch size controls how many records will be pulled from the query's remote result in each iteration. So in your case, it has to pull 100k records before it will even register data being ready. Try dropping it down to 1k records for the fetch and experiment with 100-1000 records per flowfile.

If you're bulk inserting that flowfile, you're also sending over 100k inserts at once.